# Post form and update multiple rows with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched all over this website, but not yet found the answer for this. Pr maybe I am not able to apply it correctly. I have a form that grabs all photos with a certain GALLERY_id attached to it. The backend user can then change the title of the photo and change the tags. After submitting the form the query should update all rows. Here is what I have so far which does not doe anyting:

**THE FORM**

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE gallery_id = :gallery_id ");      
    $result->bindParam(':gallery_id', $id);
    $result->execute();

    echo '<form action="" method="POST">';
    echo "<ul id='photos'>";

    for ($i = 0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
    {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $tags = $row['tags'];
        $src = $row['src'];

        echo "<li><a class='lightbox' href='images/$src'><img src='images/$src' id='$id' alt='$title' /></a><br />";
        echo "<input type='text' name='photo_title' value='$title' /><br />";
        echo "<input type='text' name='photo_tags' value='$tags' />";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='photo_id' value='$id' />";
        echo "</li>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";

}

?>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<input type="submit" name="changeTitle" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

**UPDATE QUERY**

```
if (isset($_POST['changeTitle']))
{
    foreach ($_POST as $p)
    {
        $id=$p['photo_id'];
        $title=$p['photo_title'];
        $tags=$p['photo_tags'];


        $sql = "UPDATE photos SET title=?, tags=? WHERE id=?";
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($title, $tags, $id));

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I have set error reporting. It just reloads the page, but does not submit anything neither does it give an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have multiple html fields with same names, you have to submit them as an arrays:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='photo_title[]' value='$title' /><br />";
echo "<input type='text' name='photo_tags[]' value='$tags' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='photo_id[]' value='$id' />";
```

After submitted, loop through any array variable like

```
foreach ($_POST['photo_id'] as $key => $photo_id) {
    $id = $photo_id;
    $title = $_POST['photo_title'][$key];
    $tags = $_POST['photo_tags'][$key];

    $sql = "UPDATE photos SET title=?, tags=? WHERE id=?";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array($title, $tags, $id));
}
```

Comment: This works perfect. I guess I should dive more into actually knowing what I am working with. I will invest more time in learning about php arrays etc. Thanks - super!